# Can I add more loop cuts to an existing loop cut?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edges

Sorry if this title is confusing, but what I'm looking for is pretty simple in concept.

Essentially, I'm making use of loop cut & slide to slice up long objects, and then using a Curve modifier to bend them. However, often times I find that I don't have a high enough resolution for my curve, and it starts to look chunky. As such, I need more cuts. However, I don't know how to add them. The Subdivide command works for this, in that you can select all faces and subdivide them as much as you want. However, that create a bunch of junk on the sides that I don't need.

I want to go from this:

[image: Cube loop cut twice]

to this:

[image: Cube loop cut 5 times]

without undoing, or deleting. Is there a way to do this via Loop Cut, Subdivide, or some modifier?

Comment: Select the edges that need to be divided, and not the faces. IE: edges that are parallel to the worm’s spine only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggested by Zargul, use *Edge Select Mode*.

[image]

Select these edges.

[image]

And now you can *Subdivide*.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly! I thought Zargul meant do another _loop cut_ with the edges selected, which didn't work. Thanks to you both!